# SQL Server Management Studio warns about uncommitted transactions even on selects

Tags: sql-server, select, warnings, ssms, autocommit

I've just started using SQL Server after years on Oracle - naturally the first thing I did was turn off autocommit in SQL Server Management Studio.

The "There are uncommitted transactions" warning is of course helpful in the case of a change, but I still see it even if all I've done is a single SELECT.

e.g. open session, run e.g. `select 1 from Images`, close query.

All I can think of is it might be trying to commit logging or update statistics...is there a way to turn off this warning for selects?

(I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express).

Thanks

Comment: >>>it might be trying to commit logging or update statistics<<< You cannot "commit" logging. You cannot commit update statistics. But you can use select @@trancount to find out if it was changed from 0

Comment: Your `select` can hold locks to the end of transaction, so you should manually release them

Comment: @ Ruslan K >>>Your select can hold locks to the end of transaction<<< SELECT doesn't hold locks to the end of transaction when executing in READ COMMITTED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation [Implicit Transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317(v=sql.105).aspx)

[image]

In `implicit transaction` mode your `SELECT` opens a transaction as well and it cannot be changed. That is by design.

So you'll continue to get warnings until you commit/rollback your `SELECT` statements

Comment: Thanks very much sepupic. Coming from an Oracle background it seems odd to open a transaction for a SELECT. I guess most SQL Server users keep autocommit on or they would quickly get tired of this! I get round it by having separate query windows for my selects and updates, but it does seem clunky.

Comment: yes, I also think so. This feature is not used since the default is autocommit that is usual for allSQL Server world. And in this mode SELECT does NOT open transaction unless you write begin tran explicitly